# Problem on the digits of $n!$

Tags: number-theory, problem-solving

let $m$ be a natural number, is it always possible to find an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m$ or more "$0$" digits (excluding the terminal ones) appears amongs the decimal digits of $n!$ if $n\ge N$

Comment: too many "digits" in your title...?

Comment: Do you mean for every $n>N$ ? That sounds highly unlikely, $(n+1)!$ has no reason to have as much 0s as $n!$.

Comment: He mentioned "excluding the terminal ones"

Comment: So something like this:  For all $n \ge 1000$, we have at least 23 non-terminal zeros in the decimal expansion of $n!$.  I guess that's true (in fact, a lot more than 23), but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: This looks hard enough that I think you might want to cross-post it to MathOverflow.